# Setting up two different static directories in node.js koajs framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa

How can I set up two different static directories in node.js koajs framework?

Comment: Do you want to route to one or the other depending on the request, or more of a *if not found in dirA, look in dirB* type of thing?

Answer (score 4):

Just use the koa-static middleware twice, such as:

```
'use strict';
let koa   = require('koa'),
    serve = require('koa-static'),
    app   = koa();

app.use(serve(__dirname + '/one'));
app.use(serve(__dirname + '/two'));

app.listen(3000);
```

If there were two files with the same relative path and name in both folder `one` and `two` the file in folder `one` would be used as the middleware stack will check that location first since it's added to the middleware stack first.